# Convert Blob audio file to mp3 type in typescript

Tags: typescript, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, html5-audio

I'm trying to convert a blob audio file to .mp3 type which is generated from MediaRecorder it is returning with webm type and I have tried other types in MimeType(attribute in MediaRecorder to set the type) but they are not supported so I have tried ffmpeg npm library but it was asking for path of the file but i'm not saving it so that also didn't work for me. Any suggestion and answer that will help!!

**Here is how i get audio**

```
getAudio(){
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true})
    .then( stream => {
      console.log(stream)
      this.mediaRecord = new MediaRecorder(stream)

      this.mediaRecord.ondataavailable = (data: { data: any; }) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.chunks.push(data.data)
      }

      this.mediaRecord.onstop = () => {
        const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: 'audio/mp3'})
        const reader = new window.FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const teste:any = this.$el.querySelector('#teste')
          teste.src = reader.result //render.result e o local onde o audio fica armazenado
          this.ArquivoAudio = blob
          console.log(reader.result)
        }
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
      alert('voce deve permitir a captura de audio')
    })
},
```

Comment: I don't know of any browser that supports MP3 encoding at this time.  You mentioned you were using FFmpeg, but you didn't show us any of that code.  Were you using the WASM build for client-side FFmpeg?